# calculation double integral by transformation

Tags: calculus, integration

By using the transformation $x+y=u, \; y=uv$, evaluate the integral $\int \int \sqrt{(xy(1-x-y))} dxdy$ taken over the area enclosed by the straight lines $x=0, \; y=0$ and $x+y=1$.

First I have calculated the Jacobian, it came as $u$.
By using the transformation, integrand is changed to $u\sqrt{(v(1-u)(1-v))}$. I am unable to find the new limits of the integration. Please help me with this.

Comment: You are a member of this forum for over two years. It's better if you learn how to write mathematical expressions in [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: How about looking at the old limits of the integration first, but not in terms of straight lines, but in terms of  $x$ and $y$.

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: $u = x+y, v = \frac {y}{u} = \frac y{x+y}$ the line $x+y = 1$ transforms to $u = 1$  the line $y = 0 \implies v = 0$ and $x = 0 \implies v = 1$ along those respective boundaries.

Comment: @DougM thanks a lot.